# Rearranging list of x,y points based on the shortest distance between 2 points

Tags: python

I am having a list of tuples of x,y coordinates. What algorithm I should use to rearrange those points so that I can draw a line through the points(tracing).
sample list looks like 
points=[(170, 156), (154, 154), (162, 148), (178, 164), (135, 166), (131, 166), (150, 158), (158, 150), (166, 152), (139, 166), (182, 168), (144, 163), (174, 160)]
I already tried rearrange the points based on the distance between the points. But I didn't felt it's efficient as my data set contains about 400 coordinates.

plot function in matplotlib should be able trace the points.That's my objective

Comment: What do you mean by "rearrange"? Is it a polygonal shape?

Comment: Do some research on Graph theory.  It sounds like you're trying to find the shortest path in a disconnected graph (hence re-arrange a list of points based on their closest neighbour).  Your current explanation of the problem doesn't take into account that two points may be their own closest neighbours, meaning you can't "sort" them against every other point.  

Look at this question and read about the mentioned algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317874/single-shortest-path-of-an-acyclic-undirected-disconnected-graph

Answer (score 0):

```
pts = [(4,2),(1,4),(1,8)]
df = pd.DataFrame(pts)
df.sort([0,1])
```

this will sort the points by the value of the first element, then by the second element.  So your list will be increasing

Comment: It is working for a small amount of data set. When the dataset becomes larger it was not going through the shortest path.